# Multiple questions about Perforce

Tags: perforce

I have multiple questions about Perforce :

1. Is there a way to easily select all the files in your depot/workspace to modify them all at once?
2. In the same vein, the files in my depot are not exclusive, is there a way to modify them all at once so that their filetype is "-l" AND is there a way that all new files that will be added be exclusive by default?
3. Is there a way to have a sync that wipes everything you changed locally and deletes new files you currently have in your workspace that aren't in the depot?
4. This question is pretty much the opposite of #3. Sometimes it's hard to know which files you modified and need to submit, is there a way for Perforce to automatically detect and checkout everything you modified AND also mark for add everything you added?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `p4 edit //...`
2. `p4 edit -t +l //...`; `p4 typemap` -> `+l //...`
3. `p4 clean //...`
4. `p4 reconcile //...`